# how to create an event after an event in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to repurpose code to create a custom progress bar - but I am unable to understand how to make the final change.

The current implementation does the progress bar. What I would like is for the progress bar to update the text and then disappear on its own.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  text: 'Working on it...',
  textAlign:'center',
});

var track = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: "60%", height: "20%",
    borderRadius:40, 
    backgroundColor: 'red'
});
var progress = Ti.UI.createView({
    borderRadius:40, 
    left: 0,
    width: 5, height: "100%",
    backgroundColor : "green"

});
track.add(progress);
track.add(label1);
win.add(track);

win.addEventListener('open', function () {
    progress.animate({
        width: "100%",
        duration: 1000
    });
});

win.open();
```

So when the final green progress is complete - I would like to

a. replace the "working on it" with "complete"
b. after 1000 ms - make the entire progress bar disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to add Listener for complete event, you can add anonymous function in animate method itself

e.g

```
progress.animate({
    width: "100%",
    duration: 1000
},function(e){
    label1.text = "complete";
    win.remove(track); 
});
```

Comment: awesome !! thanks.. quick question - can I add a 500ms wait after the label1 ?

Comment: progress.animate({
    width: "100%",
    duration: 500
},function(e){
    label1.text = "complete";
  setTimeout(function() {
      // request method here
      win.remove(track); 
  }, 5000);

   });

Answer (score -1):

You can use `complete` event listener of `Animation object`

```
// create the animation
  var animation = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
    width: "100%",
    duration: 1000
  });

  animation.addEventListener("complete", function onAnimationComplete(e){
     // YOUR CODE HERE
    animation.removeEventListener("complete", onAnimationComplete);
  });

progress.animate(animation);
```

More details [Titanium.UI.Animation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Animation)

Comment: HI - I am not sure how this works and inserts in the above code. sorry - I am  a novice and I am not sure.